# How to interpret op-amp differential amplifiers intuitively

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, differential-amplifier

I was looking for a simple way to understanding why the classic op-amp amplifier works the way it does. I've only found algebra-oriented explanations, but not one that gives an "electronics" argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to look, roughly and without taking the schematic notation word by word:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP5KB0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Suppose that the magic diode in the center shifts the voltages to zero (by modifying the *whole* structure's reference/ground voltage to make it exactly that!). What's the voltage of the output node? Well, we have \$V_1\$ amplified by a factor of \$\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ and \$V_2\$ amplified by a factor of \$\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$ as well! Now simply measure the voltage from \$V_o\$ by taking the amplified voltage over \$R_2\$, negative, and add the voltage over the other \$R_2\$, positively. Ta-da! The output voltage from that node to ground is \$\frac{R_2}{R_1}(V_2-V_1)\$.

I hope this helps whoever looks for another perspective to the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "intuitive" interpretation:

Seen from the left base node the left transistor works in a **common-collector** configuration (because the signal is coupled out at the emitter node). The other transistor gets the input signal at the emitter node and, hence, works ins a **common-base** configuration - and the amplified signal is available at the collector node. The same interpretation is possible from the right side.

Hint: This is not only an "intuitive" interpretation because the series connection of the described stages gives the correct overall gain:

**A=A1*A2**  with **A1=gm1*r,in2/(1+gm,1*r,in2)** and A**2=gm2*Rc**

We have r,in2=r,e||1/gm,2 which simplifies to **r,in2=1/gm** assuming gm,1=gm,2=gm and r,e>>1/gm (very large dynamic emitter resistance).

In this case, the overall gain (between the base node of one transistor and the collector of the other transistor): **A=gm*Rc/2.**